# $G$ is Abelian if it has no element of order $2$ and $(ab)^2=(ba)^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $G$ is a group that there exists no element $x \neq e$ such that $x^2=e$. Moreover, for every $a,b \in G$ we have $(ab)^2=(ba)^2$. Prove that $G$ is Abelian.

Well, I attempted to prove that $(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^2=e$ because then if I could prove it that would imply $aba^{-1}b^{-1}=e$ which is the same as $ab=ba$. In other words I wanted to show the order of $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is two for every $a$ and $b$ in $G$. I spent almost an hour trying to show that by anything that came to my mind. I tried to brute force the problem by writing any possible equation that I could come up with but I failed :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

Set $b=a^{-1}x$. We have $x^2=a^{-1}x^2a$, i.e.  $ax^2=x^2a$ for all $x,a$. Since $x^2$ runs all group, then $G$ is Abelian.

**Correction:** This proof is valid only for a finite group. Thanks to **DonAntonio**.

**Addendum:** I am not sure that this assertion is true for infinite groups. A candidate \for a counter-example is $G=\langle a,b|a^2=b^2, (ab)^2=(ba)^2\rangle$.

Comment: Why does $x^2$ run the whole group?

Comment: Actually he's right: $x^2=y^2$ if and only if $(xy^{-1})^2=e$, if and only if $x=y$.

Comment: So $x\mapsto x^2$ is at least injective. If the group is finite then it is also surjective by cardinality.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, $2\mathbb{Z}\neq\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff what does your notation mean?

Comment: But $G^2=G$ with your notation is a trivial statement, since $g=ge\in G^2$.

Comment: Nevermind, I will remove comments and add an answer (maybe), this is getting too long.

Comment: @RobertAuffarth: $\;x^2=y^2\iff x^2y^{-2}=1\;$ . How do you pass from this to $\;(xy^{-1})^2=1\;$ ??

Comment: @DonAntonio: You're right. I guess Boris Novikov's answer needs to include why $x^2$ exhausts the group.

Comment: And yet he's right, @some1.new4u...at least when the group is finite: since the order of the group is clearly odd, we can put $\;|G|=2n-1\;,\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ , and then $$x^2=y^2\implies x=x\cdot x^{2n-1}=x^{2n}=(x^2)^n=(y^2)^n=y^{2n}=y^{2n-1}\cdot y=y$$

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes, but that only settles the case when $|G|$ is finite. What if $|G|$ is infinite?

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:** Andreas Caranti have pointed out, this proof work iff the all the elements of the group have finite order. So it doesn't answer completely but
is more a partial result.

Let $x,a \in G$ then by hypothesis we have that there's $b \in G$ such that $ab=x$ then 
$$a^{-1}x^2a=a^{-1}(ab)^2a=a^{-1}ababa=baba=(ba)^2=(ab)^2=x^2$$
So $x^2 \in Z(G)$ for all $x \in G$.

So we get the quotient $G/Z(G)$ in which all the elements have order two.

If there's an $x \in G \setminus Z(G)$ then $xZ(G) \ne Z(G)$ should have order $2$, and by properties of homomorphisms of groups the order of $x$ should be divided by $2$. That's absurd since by hypothesis $G$ can't have elements of order $2$ hence it can't have either elements which have order a multiple of $2$.

Comment: $abab\neq a^2b^2$, unfortunately.

Comment: @vadim123 My bad I've misread the question. I'm gonna edit soon.

Comment: That's another problem you have in mind I guess.

Comment: @some1.new4u I was confused, now I've edited :)

Comment: @vadim123 thanks for pointing out my mistake :)

Comment: @GiorgioMossa: This is a really good answer, but I think there must be a more elementary solution to this problem. The problem has been put before the chapter that discusses homomorphisms or the center of group in my book.

Comment: @some1.new4u it's possible, anyway till now I haven't come up with nothing simpler. Btw could you tell me which book are you referring to?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa: It's a non-English book. It hasn't been published yet, so I can't actually call it a book. It's rather a set of lecture notes and problems discussed in the class + homework and other materials covered during a typical Algebra I course.

Comment: @some1.new4u if you tell me exactly what are the instrument you could use, I could try to come up with some simpler solution :)

Comment: @GiorgioMossa: Well, ideally we should use only the definition of an Abelian group and theorems that we know about groups, semi-groups, monoids and such basic stuff. :| I spent a long time trying to solve it by elementary ways, but I failed.

Comment: I don't see why $x$ could not, in principle, be an element of infinite order, with $x^2 \in Z(G)$. But maybe you are assuming $G$ finite.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti no, I'm not assuming that the group have finite order. Apparently I've assumed that the elements have finite order. I'm gonna edit the answer and add this detail. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Elementary solution to this problem.

The problem is equivalent to that the $x^2 \in Z(G)$ for any $x\in G$, as stated in a previous response.

Under these conditions we show that $(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})^4=e.$
$$(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})^4=(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})^2(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=$$
$$=(xyx^{-1})(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})^2(y^{-1})(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=$$
$$= xy(x^{-1}x)(yx^{-1}y^{-1})(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})(y^{-1})(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=$$
$$=xy^2(x^{-1}y^{-1})(xyx^{-1})(y^{-1})^2(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=$$
$$=y^2(xx^{-1})(y^{-1}xy(y^{-1})^2)(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=(yxy^{-1})(yx^{-1}y^{-1})=e.$$
Considering that the group no has elements of order $ 2 $ result, step by step, that $(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})^2=e$, $(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=e$ and $xy=yx$ and therefore the group is commutative.

Comment: It can be shown that in a group the following statements are equivalent: a) $(ab)^n=(ba)^n$, for any $a,b \in G$;  b)$a^nb=ba^n$, for any $a,b \in G$.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is the same as in the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4270671/prove-that-a-certain-group-is-abelian/4272460#4272460), just made shorter. As in the answer of [Boris Novikov](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/62565/boris-novikov), for every $x\in G$ the element $x^2$ is in the centralizer of $Z(G)$ of $G$, by using
$(ab)^2=(ba)^2$ for $b=a^{-1}x$:
$$
x^2 =(ab)^2=(ba)^2=(a^{-1}xa)^2=a^{-1}x^2a\ .
$$
Let now $s,t\in G$ be two elements. We show $st=ts$. Consider
$$a = s^{-2}t^{-2}\; stst\ .
$$
One easily shows $a^2=1$ by using $s^{\pm 2},t^{\pm 2}\in Z(G)$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
a^2 
&= s^{-4}t^{-4}\cdot stst\cdot stst\\
&= s^{-4}t^{-4}\cdot stst\cdot tsts\\
&= s^{-4}t^{-4}\cdot sts\cdot t^2\cdot sts\\
&= s^{-4}t^{-2}\cdot st\cdot s^2\cdot ts\\
&= s^{-2}t^{-2}\cdot s\cdot t^2\cdot s\\
&= s^{-2}\cdot s^2\\
&=1\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
From the assumption, $a=1$, i.e.
$$
1=s^{-2}\; stst\; t^{-2}=s^{-1}\; ts\; t^{-1}\ ,
$$
so after multiplying from left with $s$, and from right with $t$ we get
$st=ts$.

$\square$

Answer (score 0):

$\forall x,a\in G,ax,a^{-1} \in G\Rightarrow ax^2a^{-1}=x^2\Rightarrow ax^2=x^2a$

$\forall x,y\in G$

$xyxy=yxyx\Rightarrow x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=yxy^{-1}x^{-1}$

$(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})^2=xy(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)x^{-1}y^{-1}=xy^2xy^{-1}(x^{-1})^2y^{-1}$=$x^2y^2y^{-2}x^{-2}=e$

$order(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})\neq 2\Rightarrow xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=e$

$xy=yx$

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

## $(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^4=(aba^{-1}b^{-1})(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^2(aba^{-1}b^{-1})\\$
$=(aba^{-1}b^{-1})(a^{-1}b^{-1}ab)^2(aba^{-1}b^{-1})\\$
$=aba^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}aba^{-1}b^{-1}ababa^{-1}b^{-1}\\$
$=ab(a^{-1}b^{-1})^2aba^{-1}b^{-1}(ab)^2a^{-1}b^{-1}\\$
$=ab(b^{-1}a^{-1})aba^{-1}b^{-1}(ba)^2a^{-1}b^{-1}\\$
$=abb^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}aba^{-1}b^{-1}baba^{-1}b^{-1}\\$
$=eeee=e\implies (aba^{-1}b^{-1})^2=e\implies (aba^{-1}b^{-1})=e\implies ab=ba$